# How to insert values in the different table by adding values to only one table using sql query?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-server

I have a table 'Person' with columns as 'Person_id as primary key','DOB' and 'place' as follows:

```
'Person'
 Person_id |Name|DOB | place
```

Another table is "employee" where emp_id is primary key as follows:

```
 'employee'
 Person_id |emp_id|dateofjoin
```

And one more table "Details":

```
 'Details'
 emp_id|competency|rating
```

Now what i want is once i add the 'Person' table details the rest of the two tables as'employe' and 'Details' to get updated also with respect to the new Person added in the Person table. So, how can i have this using sql query? Also i want to clear that i am not very much familiar with database.

Comment: This would typically be done with a stored procedure that will insert into all three tables.

Comment: Person name as PK isn't the best of ideas IMHO. What if you have two people named "John Smith"?

Comment: @scsimon you are right but lets ignore that case consider as name to be different all the time.

Comment: @SeanLange could you please elaborate more. I did not got your point

Answer (score 2):

I think your after something like this ( for SQL Server ):

```
Create Procedure dbo.CreateMyEmployee ( @empName varchar(50), 
@dob datetime, 
@doj datetime, 
@place as varchar(100), 
@competency varchar(100), 
@rating int)
As
Begin
  Declare @empId int
  Begin Transaction
  Begin Try
    Insert into Person (Name, DOB, Place)
    Values ( @empName, @dob, @place)
    Insert into employe (Name, dateofJoin) -- Assuming emp_id is identity columen
    Values ( @empName, @doj)
    Select @empId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    Insert Into Details(emp_id, competency, rating)
    Values (@empId, @competency, @rating)
    Commit transaction
  End Try
  Begin Catch
    Rollback Transaction
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
  End Catch
End
```